# Interrupción en interfaz gráfica

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, wxwidgets

Buen dia, me encuentro realizando un programa donde necesito detener (en caso de ser necesario) una accion que es un ciclo, hice un pequeño programa simulando lo mismo para despues adaptarlo pero no logro interrumpir el ciclo, ya que al precionar detener el programa se bloquea, de hecho segun parece una vez inicia el ciclo el los botoner parecen no estar disponibles. ¿Existe alguna funcion para interrupciones? les dejo el codigo, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Jun 17 2015)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.xrc
import time

###########################################################################
## Class MyFrame1
###########################################################################
num=1

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.static = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyLabel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.static.Wrap( -1 )
        self.static.SetForegroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_BTNTEXT ) )
        self.static.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT ) )

        bSizer1.Add( self.static, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.ini = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"iniciar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.ini, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.det = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"detener", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.det, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.ini.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.start )
        self.det.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.stop )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def start( self, event ):   
        global num  
        num=1
        for i in range (100):
            if num==1:
                self.static.SetLabel("Numero %fmm" %i)
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                i=100

    def stop( self, event ):
        global num
        num=0



app = wx.App()
fr = MyFrame1(None)
fr.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: No puedes usar métodos o funciones bloqueantes dentro de una GUI en general. Los ciclos, `time.sleep`, `input`, etc son bloqueantes, esto ocasiona que el `mainloop` de tu GUI se bloquee y la interfaz se congela dejando de responder. Necesitas usar algún método que permita concurrencia como hilos, procesos, corrutinas, etc para que el proceso bloqueante no interfiera con el mainloop. Tambíén vas a necesitar comunicar ambos procesos de forma adecuada y segura (sincronización)

Comment: Algo asi imaginaba que ese tipo de ciclos bloqueaban al programa hasta que estos terminen. Acerca de hilos, procesos y corrutinas no se absolutamente nada ¿me podrias decir cual me recomiendas para empezar a estudiarlo y enfocarme en uno solo?

Comment: Jorge he creado una respuesta para darte un ejemplo de como se puede abordar el problema usando hilos estándar de Python, que es quizás lo más simple. He de decir que no domino wxWidgets (es quizás el único framework para interfaces gráficas de Python que no he tocado) por lo que puede que pase por alto algo (aunque el manejo de estos problemas es muy similar entre frameworks). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como te comenté no puedes usar métodos o funciones bloqueantes dentro de una GUI en general. Cualquier función/método o estructura que no retorne de forma "inmediata" como `time.sleep`, `input`, ciclo `while`, etc son bloqueantes.

Por norma general, una interfáz gráfica se ejecuta usando un ciclo principal (mainloop) que se encarga de redibujar constantemente la interfaz permitiendo que esta responde de forma adecuada a los eventos generados. Si en el mismo proceso se ejecuta cualquier cosa que no responda en un tiempo corto (sin usar concurrencia) el mainloop se bloquea y la interfaz se congela dejando de responder.

Para solucionar estos problemas necesitas usar algún método que permita concurrencia como hilos, procesos, corrutinas, etc para que el proceso bloqueante no interfiera con el mainloop. También vas a necesitar comunicar ambos procesos de forma adecuada y segura (sincronización).

Lo más simple es usar un hilo y comunicarse con el usando algún método seguro. Una opción es usar una cola ([queue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html)) . No obstante, la gran mayoría de frameworks proveen métodos para poder comunicarse con otros hilos o procesos de forma segura (`@mainthread` en Kivy, `QThread` y señalen en `Qt`, etc).

En wxWidgets también existen métodos para hacer esto. Puedes usar eventos o usar  [`wx.CallAfter`](https://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter) junto a  [`wx.lib.pubsub`](https://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) para enviar mensajes entre objetos.

Además de esto quieres poder "pausar" el hilo. Para ello debes establecer métodos apropiados para iniciar, pausar, reanudar y detener la ejecución de un hilo. Hay muchas formas de abordar estos problemas, dependiendo tambíen de lo que quieras hacer.

Si no conoces nada sobre hilos te aconsejo aprender primero el concepto de hilo, la importancia de la sincronización y las formas de conseguirla (semáforos, candados, etc), que debes y que no debes hacer cuando interactuas con varios hilos, etc. Te dejo el enlace a la documentación del módulo `threading` de Python donde puedes encontrar la información sobre los métodos que voy a usar en el ejemplo que te dejaré a continuación:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects

Explicar como implementar lo que quieres desde cero y con detalle es bastante extenso, ya que existen como digo muchas formas de abordarlo. Para centrarnos en algo te voy a dejar un ejemplo en donde ejecutamos un determinado código bloqueante en un hilo (en este caso va a ser un simple contador junto a un `sleep()` para simular un tiempo "largo" de procesamiento). El hilo puede ser lanzado y detenido usando la ventana principal de tu GUI, además podemos pausar y reanudar el proceso llevado a cabo por el hilo en cualquier momento.

Para poder pausar y reanudar un hilo podemos usar igualmente varias aproximaciones. En este caso se usa una condición ([`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects)) asociada a un candado para permitir pausar y reanudar el hilo, aunque existen otras formas, como el uso de [eventos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects).

Te dejo el código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import time
from threading import Thread

import wx
import wx.xrc
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

###########################################################################
## class Worker
###########################################################################

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.on = True
        self.paused = False
        self.condition = threading.Condition(threading.Lock())

    def run(self):
        n = 0
        while self.on:
            with self.condition:
                while self.paused:
                    self.pause_cond.wait()
                n += 1
                wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'actualizar', value=n)
            time.sleep(2)

    def pause(self):
        # Al pausar cambiamos la varible de control y adquirimos el candado
        if not self.paused:
            self.paused = True
            self.condition.acquire()

    def resume(self):
        # Al reanudar liberamos el candado
        if self.paused:
            self.paused = False
            self.condition.notify()
            self.condition.release()

    def stop(self):
        self.on = False


###########################################################################
## Class MyFrame1
###########################################################################

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.static = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Inicie un hilo", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.static.Wrap( -1 )
        self.static.SetForegroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_BTNTEXT ) )
        self.static.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT ) )
        bSizer1.Add( self.static, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.ini = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"iniciar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.ini, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.det = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"detener", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.det, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.rea = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"reanudar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.rea, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.pau = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"pausar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.pau, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)


        self.ini.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._start_thread )
        self.det.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._stop_thread )
        self.pau.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._pause_thread )
        self.rea.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._resume_thread )

        self.det.Disable()
        self.pau.Disable()
        self.rea.Disable()

        pub.subscribe(self._update_label, "actualizar")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self._when_closed)

        self.hilo = None


    def _update_label(self, value):
        self.static.SetLabel("Numero {}".format(value))

    def _start_thread(self, event):
        self.ini.Disable()
        self.det.Enable()
        self.pau.Enable()
        self.rea.Disable()

        self.hilo = Worker()
        self.hilo.start()

    def _stop_thread(self, event):
        if self.hilo:
            self.hilo.stop()

            self.det.Disable()
            self.pau.Disable()
            self.rea.Disable()
            self.ini.Enable()

    def _pause_thread(self, event):
        if self.hilo:
            self.hilo.pause()

            self.pau.Disable()
            self.rea.Enable()

    def _resume_thread(self, event):
        if self.hilo:
            self.hilo.resume()

            self.pau.Enable()
            self.rea.Disable()

    def _when_closed(self, event):
        self._stop_thread(event)
        event.Skip()

    def __del__(self):
        pass



app = wx.App()
fr = MyFrame1(None)
fr.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Podemos verlo en funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema de los hilos y de la concurrencia en general es muy extenso y complejo como para explicar en una respuesta. Esto es solo un ejemplo de una de las muchas formas de abordar el problema. El código está probado bajo Python 3.6.1 con wxWidgets 4.0.0a3.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta gran respuesta! me pondre a estudiar esto de los hilos para poder adaptarlo a mi codigo correctamente, gracias.

Comment: Disuculpa, una pregunta mas ¿Con que programa hiciste el gif? me podria funcionar para presentar mis trabajos.

Comment: @JorgeSanchezRodriguez uso [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/), la verdad es que para esto es muy cómodo. Permite capturar el trozo de pantalla que quieras, pausar-reanudar la grabación, eliminar/agragar/editar frames, agragar marcas de agua, etc . Y es  open source. Lo malo es que es solo para Windows. Saludos.